# $.post & AJAX is not working on server, but working fine in localhost

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, server

I just moved my website on server and got socked by the result, `$.post()` and AJAX is not working on server.

`$.post()` is always returning blank data. You can check in below one sample of `$.post()` in this case, when im `alert(info)` it shows `Array()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#faq").submit(function () {
        var data = $(this).serializeArray();
        $.post("worker.php", data, function (info) {
            $(".faq_status").fadeOut();
            $(".faq_body").prepend(info);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The same thing is happening with all the `$.post()` & `AJAX` code. I don't know what to do.

Here is my worker.php progress:

```
$question = addslashes(htmlentities($_POST['user_question']));
$uip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if ($question == "") {
    echo "<p class='alert alert-danger faq_status'>Problem in posting your query. Please resubmit it.</p>";
    exit;
}

$day = date('d');
$month = date('m');
$year = date('Y');

$sql = "SELECT no FROM user_faq WHERE user_ip = '$uip' AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM asked_time) = $month AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM asked_time) = $day AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM asked_time) = $year";

$record = $conn->query($sql);

if ($record->rowCount() >= 2) {
    echo "<p class='alert alert-danger faq_status'>Problem in posting your query. please resubmit it.</p>";
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `user_faq`(`no`, `question`, `user_ip`,`asked_date`) VALUES (NULL,:que,:ip,Now())";

    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(":que", $question, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(":ip", $uip, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    try {
        $query->execute();
        echo "<p class='alert alert-success faq_status'>We have receive your question, answer will be posted here soon!</p>";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "<p class='alert alert-danger faq_status'>Problem in posting your query. please resubmit it.</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your PHP is returning the *text* `Array()` (but more likely `array()`) and probably with the response type of `text/plain`. There is nothing in the JavaScript that causes this. Validate the response by looking at the *network request monitor* in the developer tools. After isolating the 'real' source of the problem, make sure to include the *relevant* code.

Comment: Can you provide us the link of website ?

Comment: Here is the link : www.thevende.com

Comment: specially you can check here live example, when you will ask some question on this page : http://www.thevende.com/info.php?ref=help

Comment: Show your **worker.php** code.

Comment: change the error message in try catch.and then check if error coming at the top or at the bottom

Comment: this is the not only one $.post() case, there are 40+ $.post() operations. infect they all are working nicely in localhost. but not working on server.

Comment: please try to change your error messages so you can see which error is printed. (Use a unique message for each error)

Comment: Yes @NicoMartin is correct

Comment: Does your mysql connection work on other non-ajax requests?

Comment: its not returning anything, only blank blank. but question is why its not working on server? these all this working accurately in localhost

Comment: yes, connection working properly!

Comment: Which one of the error messages is working?

Comment: change PHP error_reporting to `E_ALL` so you can view errors you may have.

Comment: Run your query `INSERT INTO `user_faq`(`no`, `question`, `user_ip`,`asked_date`) VALUES (NULL,:que,:ip,Now());` directly on your server SQL.

Comment: yes, good idea with E_ALL in PHP

Comment: yup, that all the sql statements are working good on server too, but things is $.post() is not responding

Comment: Sounds like this is because of paths.. Try replacing `$.post("worker.php"` with `$.post("/worker.php"` (note the slash)

Comment: all files are in the same folder, will it gonna work?

Comment: is PDO extension enabled on the server ?

Comment: yes, PDO is working fine

Comment: Check the Exception!

Answer (score 0):

Your post is working and returning this response on submit.

```
<p class='alert alert-danger faq_status'>Problem in posting your query. please resubmit it.</p>
```

Add [Firebug extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/) to Firefox to easily debug your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that some configuration or error reporting on your localhost supresses or ignores warnings which doesn't on your server. The most effective way would be :

1.Check for any javascript errors in your console related to your code.

2.Echo something in your code at possible lines and debug to find where your script breaks.

3.If you find the breakpoint, turn ON error reporting and check if
   there are any warnings/errors

Comment: but miracle is how does it all works until users visiting 5 - 6 pages. problem are occurring after some pageviews. until that everything is working fine.

Comment: @VijayMakwana Can u check what input is passed to the script when the user moves to 5th or 6th page? Check if it is parsed properly and is not blank or null